# probability of projection vector

Tags: probability, matrices

Let Q be projection in $R^m$ of rank $n$.
Let $X=(x_1,...,x_m)$ be a vector with i.i.d components, i.e. $x_1,..., x_n$ are independent and identical distributed.
Suppose that probability of the Euclidean norm $$P(\|QX\|>K)\leq \frac{1}{K^c}$$ for $c>0$ and $K> n)$.

What we can say about $P(|x_i|>K), i=1,...,m$?

Comment: Could you use a different symbol for your projection?  $P$ for probability and for projection is a bit confusing.

Comment: @ Dilip Sarwate: You are right. Thank you.